# Accessing Backend API from Python client (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have already developed a backend api for a project using Google App Engine. The backend (written in Java) currently has one protected method that returns a list of strings. The issue that I'm having is accessing this backend from a python client; specifically accessing the backend that I've written. The error that I'm getting is coming from setting up the credentials in the following code.

```
def main():
  # Parse command line flags used by the oauth2client library.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description='Auth sample',
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args(args=[])

  # Acquire and store oauth token.
  storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('<PROJECT_NAME>.json')
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope=SCOPE,
        user_agent=USER_AGENT,
        xoauth_displayname=OAUTH_DISPLAY_NAME)
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  # Build a service object for interacting with the API.
  api_root = 'https://localhost:8080/_ah/api'
  api = '<BACKEND_API_NAME>'
  version = 'v1'
  discovery_url = '%s/discovery/v1/apis/%s/%s/rest' % (api_root, api, version)
  service = discovery.build(
      api, version, discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url, http=http)

  # Fetch all greetings and print them out.
  response = service.greetings().list().execute()
  return response
```

This code is the example they give on the App Engine Website (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python) however, when "tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)" is run I get this error: "RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)" Any suggestion as to why this is happening? Or does anyone know a better way to access OAuth protected methods? Thank you.